# OIOUBL Order XML file fails schematron validation (XSLT) - DocumentType mismatch

Tags: xml, xslt

I have created an Order XML file according to the OIOUBL standard, but have run into an issue when I run it through the online validation tool ( http://www.oioubl.info/validator/default.aspx ). The error message reads:

```
Checking OIOUBL-2.02 Order, 2013-09-15, Version 1.5.0
The document can not pass the schematron validation.
1 error(s) occurred.

Error No. : 1
Context : /
Pattern : namespace-uri(*) = 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Order-2'
Description : [F-ORD254] The documenttype does not match an OIOUBL Order and can not be validated by this schematron.
XPath : 

Fuld fejlbesked Xml : 
<Information>Checking OIOUBL-2.02 Order, 2013-09-15, Version 1.5.0</Information><Error context="/"><Pattern>namespace-uri(*) = 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Order-2'</Pattern><Description>[F-ORD254] The documenttype does not match an OIOUBL Order and can not be validated by this schematron.</Description><Xpath /></Error>
```

I have not been able to find any OIOUBL documentation to explain how to correct this.  Would appreciate some assistance.

Following is the XML document

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">
<cbc:UBLVersionID>2.0</cbc:UBLVersionID>
<cbc:CustomizationID>OIOUBL-2.02</cbc:CustomizationID>
<cbc:ProfileID schemeID="urn:oioubl:id:profileid-1.2">Procurement-OrdSim-BilSim-1.0</cbc:ProfileID>
<cbc:ID>Referencenummer</cbc:ID>
<cbc:IssueDate>2014-06-12</cbc:IssueDate>
<cbc:Note>THIS IS A TEST ORDER! </cbc:Note>
<cac:BuyerCustomerParty>
  <cac:Party>
    <cbc:EndpointID schemeID="DK:CVR">hhw123456</cbc:EndpointID>
    <cac:PartyIdentification>
      <cbc:ID schemeID="DK:CVR">hhw123456</cbc:ID>
    </cac:PartyIdentification>
    <cac:PartyName>
      <cbc:Name>HHW</cbc:Name>
    </cac:PartyName>
    <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
      <cbc:RegistrationName>HHW</cbc:RegistrationName>
      <cbc:CompanyID schemeID="DK:CVR">hhw123456</cbc:CompanyID>
    </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
    <cac:Contact>
      <cbc:Name>He hongwei</cbc:Name>
      <cbc:ElectronicMail>he.hong.wei@163.com</cbc:ElectronicMail>
    </cac:Contact>
  </cac:Party>
</cac:BuyerCustomerParty><cac:SellerSupplierParty>
  <cac:Party>
    <cbc:EndpointID schemeID="DK:CVR">15908416</cbc:EndpointID>
    <cac:PartyIdentification>
      <cbc:ID schemeID="DK:CVR">15908416</cbc:ID>
    </cac:PartyIdentification>
    <cac:PartyName>
      <cbc:Name>Solar</cbc:Name>
    </cac:PartyName>
    <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
      <cbc:CompanyID schemeID="DK:CVR">15908416</cbc:CompanyID>
    </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
  </cac:Party>
</cac:SellerSupplierParty><cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
  <cbc:SupplierAssignedAccountID>333333</cbc:SupplierAssignedAccountID>
  <cac:Party>
    <cac:PartyName>
      <cbc:Name>HHW</cbc:Name>
    </cac:PartyName>
    <cac:PostalAddress>
      <cbc:AddressFormatCode>StructuredLax</cbc:AddressFormatCode>
      <cbc:StreetName>Shuangjing</cbc:StreetName>
      <cbc:CityName>Beijing</cbc:CityName>
      <cbc:PostalZone>100020</cbc:PostalZone>
      <cac:Country>
        <cbc:IdentificationCode>DK</cbc:IdentificationCode>
      </cac:Country>
    </cac:PostalAddress>
  </cac:Party>
</cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
<cac:Delivery>
  <cac:DeliveryLocation>
    <cbc:Description>Cheese Factory One</cbc:Description>
    <cac:Address>
      <cbc:AddressFormatCode>StructuredLax</cbc:AddressFormatCode>
      <cbc:StreetName>11 Cheesey Street</cbc:StreetName>
      <cbc:BuildingNumber></cbc:BuildingNumber>
      <cbc:CityName>Cheeseville</cbc:CityName>
      <cbc:PostalZone>11113</cbc:PostalZone>
      <cac:Country>
        <cbc:IdentificationCode>DK</cbc:IdentificationCode>
      </cac:Country>
    </cac:Address>
  </cac:DeliveryLocation>
</cac:Delivery>
<cac:AnticipatedMonetaryTotal>
  <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="DKK">9335.00</cbc:PayableAmount>
</cac:AnticipatedMonetaryTotal>
<cac:OrderLine>
  <cac:LineItem>
    <cbc:ID>5705154000016</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:Quantity unitCode="EA">100</cbc:Quantity>
    <cac:Price>
      <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="DKK">93.35</cbc:PriceAmount>
      <cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="EA">1</cbc:BaseQuantity>
    </cac:Price>
    <cac:Item>
      <cbc:Description></cbc:Description>
      <cbc:Name>LYGTE GUL FOR 2D BATTERIER       S</cbc:Name>
      <cac:BuyersItemIdentification>
        <cbc:ID schemeName="EAN">5705154000016</cbc:ID>
      </cac:BuyersItemIdentification>
      <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
        <cbc:ID schemeName="EAN">5705154000016</cbc:ID>
      </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
    </cac:Item>
  </cac:LineItem>
</cac:OrderLine>
</Order>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the rather large XSLT file at http://www.oioubl.info/validator/xslt/OIOUBL_Order_Schematron.xsl, if you do a search on the text "*The documenttype does not match an OIOUBL Order and can not be validated by this schematron*", you will find it occurs in the **xsl:otherwise** of this block of code

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="namespace-uri(*) = 'urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Order-2'"/>
   <xsl:otherwise>
      <Error> ....
```

And this particular **xsl:choose** occurs in the following template match

```
 <xsl:template mode="M14" match="/" priority="3999">
```

So, the code is looking the root element (**Order** in this case), and checking it is in the namespace "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Order-2". However, your XML starts as follows...

```
<Order xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" 
       xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">
```

In other words, your **Order** element is NO namespace.

The fix in this case, is to add the missing namespace, like so

```
<Order xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Order-2" 
       xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" 
       xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">
```

(Note, when you do this, you may find you still get other errors elsewhere, but they are all separate issues for you to work out!)

Comment: Agree, the standard namespace is missing

Answer (score 0):

This is your header with relevant information

```
<Order 
    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Order-2" 
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" 
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" 
    xmlns:ccts="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CoreComponentParameters-2" 
    xmlns:sdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:SpecializedDatatypes-2" 
    xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Order-2 UBL-Order-2.0.xsd">
```

Please check documentation and guide lines
https://www.oioubl.info/Classes/en/Order.html
https://oioubl.info/Classes/da/Guidance.html

Please note: Your attached example is not valid.
From the validation on oioubl.info
*An error occurred during validation: Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. Line 2, position 3.*

With the comments removed and missing namespaces added you have 15 other schematron errors
Missing data, invalid quantity formatting etc